how do i find the local ip that ports are forwarded to from an external port and ip address?
I have a global IP and port, however I have the case where a router doesn't support NAT loopback, so I cant use this, and I need to use the local IP address and the internal port that it's forwarded to. I'm already aware that i can get around this via the following:

if the port is forwarded via UPnP i can simply query for the local IP and port using a library
I can use a vpn or proxy so that i can actually connect from outside the network.

However is there a solution that doesnt involve either of these two methods?

Unless the router provides a way to query its NAT table programmatically  (e.g. via SNMP) I don't think there's an easy way to automate this.

you could use web scraping to connect to the router's web interface and extract the port forwarding from there.
